# Assume $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Is this change of variables valid: $y=x^{\frac{1}{m}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, contour-integration, complex-integration

Consider the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x^{\frac{1}{m}})dx$  where $f$ is smooth and has compact support and $m$ is odd.

Can one change variables $y=x^{\frac{1}{m}}$ ?

My concern is about the negative values of $x$. If $x$ is a real negative number, then we know that $y$ does take a negative real value. But this is precisely one of the $m$ different values of the $m$th root of $x<0$. The other $m-1$ roots are all complex with a nonzero imaginary part. Note that if $m$ is even then $y^m=x$ has $m$ complex roots none of which is real.

Comment: If $m$ is odd then there's no issue. In order for $f(x^{\frac{1}{m}})$ to even make sense unambiguously you must be taking the unique negative real root. The other roots are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you  Qiaochu Yuan.